# How can an existing systemd service become unknown again?

Tags: debian, systemd

I have a custom system service running on a server, let's call it `xyz.service`. It has been running for months without problems and is also enabled to run on reboot (`WantedBy=multi-user.target`).

When I last checked on it however, it was neither running nor known to systemd:

```
$ systemctl status xyz
Unit xyz.service could not be found.
$ systemctl list-units | grep xyz
$
```

The file in `/etc/systemd/system` and the symlink in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` still exist. After a `systemctl daemon-reload`, the service is available again and (after starting) running fine.

I can see (via `journalctl -u xyz`) that the service was stopped yesterday.

What could cause this, and is there a way to find out when that happened?

Comment: Seems odd that the service would stop unexpectedly. Is there more evidence in the journalctl log (`journalctl -u xyz`) ? Is there some sort of deployment tool that would be uninstalling and reinstalling the service? ("stop xyz, remove xyz, install xyz" -- but not "start xyz")?

Comment: The only other thing that's interesting is a reboot of the system that I don't know the exact cause of yet. Before the reboot the service was shut down as usual, and afterwards the situation was as described above.

Comment: I have not yet found a solution, but stumbled across [this](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8307), suggesting that having the unit files on a partition that is not mounted before systems starts that might be the problem. I will post this as an answer when I'm more sure this is the correct diagnosis.